# Vertical alignment with tcbimage comment

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

Consider the following MWE and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings}

\newtcblisting{test}{listing side comment, tcbimage comment={example-image.pdf}}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
one liner
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: middle]

It shows the following output with the upper part (the listing) being vertically centered. My aim is to have the upper part aligned at the top of the main box. I have tried all kinds of combination of `valign=top` within the main style, the `comment style` etc. But none of the vertical alignment options seemed to have the desired effect. And my search has been quite unsuccessful (maybe I did not have the right keywords, `valign` or `vertical alignment` seem not to yield anything of interest).

*Question:* How to align the upper part of the tcolorbox at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
sidebyside align=top seam
```

(see p. 120 of manual v4.30) as in

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings}
\newtcblisting{test}{
  listing side comment,
  sidebyside align=top seam,
  tcbimage comment={example-image.pdf}}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
one liner
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Many thanks :) I would not have guessed that name :D

Comment: @TeXnician Please do not not ask how I found it.... ;-) (It was with `grep tcb@box@align /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/*`  .... ;-)